# Using AWS API Gateway for private APIs, is it possible to have a single endpoint that is configured to be public?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am curious if it is possible to have an AWS API Gateway (private apis) but to configure a *single* endpoint to be public. Is this possible?

For example, lets suppose that I have a rest-full api which has 100 endpoints. 99 of those endpoints will be called by clients within the private network. However, 1 client needs to make a request to a public endpoint since it *cannot* be grouped in the private network, for various reasons.

Is it possible to make accommodations for that specific client and specific endpoint/operation?

Comment: From AWS standpoint - No 
However, you could have a workaround of using a Lambda function to authenticate the source IP address for each API. This will ensure that only one endpoint has public access and rest of them have private access.